# Not redirecting to login page after session expires in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I am using a filter to check if user is authenticated. If not need to redirect to login page.

```
public class CookieAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
 protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (authorized)
        {
            FormsIdentity identity = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
            System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(identity.Ticket);

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            httpContext.Items["redirectToCompleteProfile"] = true;

            return false;
        }

    }
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Items.Contains("redirectToCompleteProfile"))
        {
            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Login",
                action = "Login",
            });
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
        }

   }


}
```

}

Even though code is entering Login controller , redirection is not working.
The request is coming from javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Global.asax.cs, you can catch the ajax request using `context.Request.IsAjaxRequest` and use `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` event.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);

    if(context.User == null || !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if(context.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var loginPageUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, "Login", "Account", null, RouteTable.Routes, HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext, false);
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            Response.Clear();
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            Response.StatusCode = (Int32)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(new
            {
                Url = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath,
                LoginUrl = loginPageUrl
            }));
            Response.End();
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

and in your javascript, you can have a global handler for these errors like

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
    if (jqxhr.status == 401) {
        var errorObject = $.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText);
        var pageUrl = errorObject.Url;
        var loginUrl = errorObject.LoginUrl;
        window.location = loginUrl + "?ReturnUrl=" + pageUrl;
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ajax call case redirection will not work, it will just return the Login View html back as reponse of ajax call.

You have to check if it is a ajax request return status and url to which should be redirect in JSON format:

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Items.Contains("redirectToCompleteProfile") && !context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new
    {
        controller = "Login",
        action = "Login",
    });
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
}
else
{
   filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
   filterContext.Result = new JsonResult 
                              { 

                                  Data = "LogOut",
                                  JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet 
                              };
}
```

and in your master layout, you can write:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, opts) {

            console.log(xhr.status);
            if (xhr.status == 403 && && xhr.responseText.indexOf("LogOut") != -1) {

                window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Login", "Login")";
            }

        });
```